# How do I push a form to Marketo

Tags: c#, forms, sitecore, marketo

Hey I wanted to know how would I go about pushing a form created in c# to Marketo, The form has the same fields as the form created in Marketo. The reason I'm not just using the embed is to control the field names for multilingual they are set up in sitecore.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to push the values I get from a form I have created in c# to marketo. without using the Marketo Form 2.0 embed.That a little bit clearer?

Comment: Are you using the WFFM module or just a standard .net form?

Comment: Standard .Net form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently for a project. After going back and forth with Marketo about things, it seems there is no way around using the form embed if you want to be able to rely progressive profiling, etc. However, you can still create your own form (so that you can use the multilingual field names as you desire) and then embed a hidden Marketo form, and push the values from the "real" form into the hidden form by following this process:

http://developers.marketo.com/blog/make-a-marketo-form-submission-in-the-background/

I'm cringing thinking about this now, but it does work.

Comment: Hey sorry yes that worked like a charm. I'll post the code I used. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Like I said, it's not a great solution but as far as I know it's the best option available now.

Comment: For Marketo making 100's of millions of dollars per year, and having no real solution for this, it is just pathetic.